# jsFiddle alternatives to store large collection of scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

While jsFiddle is great to run your JS code right away, easy to add popular libraries, etc etc, it's **very** inconvenient to store scripts at - in your dashboard you **always** see the first name that you gave to the script or hash, if you didn't name your script. That's a deal breaker, jsFiddle is clearly not made to use it this way.

Do you know any alternatives, that address this issue?

Comment: there is also http://jsbin.com/

Comment: jsfiddle is just a temporary tool to try code... but you can anyway add script tags in the html of a jsfiddle check: http://jsfiddle.net/dhrBt/

Comment: You can always fork your code and then rename it using the fiddle options if you want it to have a new name

Comment: codepen is really good i think

Comment: How about using GitHub?

Comment: Thanks, codepen does address this issue! Please answer so that I can accept it (I believe @aldanux was the first...)

Comment: @jgroenen I think GitHub is overkill here. These are just sample scripts, unlikely to change, don't really need version control.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Online JavaScript IDE may help you: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following as well:

[liveweave.com](http://liveweave.com)